# Can I delete /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs?

Tags: macos

I have a problem. Inside this directory, /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs I have 5 folders (MacOSX.sdk, MacOSX10.15.sdk, MacOSX11.1.sdk, MacOSX11.3.sdk, MacOSX11.sdk)
Now I need to program on the command line from terminal, (using gcc), is it a problem if I delete these folders since they are contained within the CommandLineTool folder?

Attention, i don't want to delete the whole directory, only the 5 folders

Comment: Why do you need to delete the folder?

Comment: I need more space, unfortunately I only have 128 gb and these folders occupy 1.50, so some memory recovered

Comment: Which macOS version?

Comment: BigSur, 11.6 version

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.